# Plotting a piecewise function for probability

Tags: overleaf, plot

I'm trying to plot the function in the image below.

I tried writing some code like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-6em}

% Enter the specific assignment number and topic of that assignment below, and replace "Your Name" with your actual name.


\begin{document}
Test
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= (\x < 0) * (0)   +
              and(\x >= 0, \x < 1 * (0.5)     +
              (\x >= 1) * (2 * \x))
   ;
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]

\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

And that code does not produce what I'd like shown below. Where am I going wrong?

I did review other questions on the forum, but seem to be missing some understanding of declaring functions properly.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. You need to increase the number of samples to get the vertical line of the function.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%  <<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    funcx(\x)= 
      (\x < 0) * (0))  + 
      and(\x >= 0, \x <1) * (0.5) +
      and(\x >= 1, \x <= 2) * (0.5*\x)  +
      (\x >= 2) * (1));
    }]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
        ymin=0, ymax=2, ytick={0,0.5,...,1}, ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=-1, xmax=3, xtick={0,1,...,2}, xlabel=$x$,
        domain=-1:3, samples=300, % added samples
        ]
    
        \addplot[thick]{funcx(x)};
    \end{axis}  

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**OPCION**

If you do not want the vertical line plot the function twice: a left part and a right part with different domains.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            funcx(\x)= 
            (\x < 0) * (0))  + 
            and(\x >= 0, \x <1) * (0.5) +
            and(\x >= 1, \x <= 2) * (0.5*\x)  +
            (\x >= 2) * (1));
        }]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
            ymin=0, ymax=2, ytick={0,0.5,...,1}, ylabel=$y$,
            xmin=-1, xmax=3, xtick={0,1,...,2}, xlabel=$x$,
            samples=100, % 
            ]
            
        \addplot[red, domain=0.01:3, thick]{funcx(x)};
        \addplot[red, domain=-1:-0.01,thick]{funcx(x)};
        \end{axis}  
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```